# Stop printf from padding exponent

Tags: c

When I use this:

```
printf("%e", 2000.0);
```

I get output `2.000000e+003` which is correct but very ugly. I then tried like this:

```
printf("%.1e", 2000.0);
```

Which outputs `2.0e+003` which is far better. The question is how to remove the 2 padding zeroes in the exponent so that the output is `2.0e+3`. Is there a specific `printf` specifier for that or do I have to write a function manually that analyzes the floating point number and prints it the way I want (I'd hate to have to do that)?

Comment: Check your system version of  `man 3 printf`. The conversion specifier `e, E` may hold this information. In my case, the exposant will always contains at least two digits.

Comment: Are you sure the output from the first version was “2.000000e+003”? Per the C standard, “The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent.” (C 2018 7.21.6.1 8.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard C features for `printf` do not provide any means of controlling the number of digits in the exponent. If you want a different format, you will have to write your own code or obtain code from somewhere else.

(The `%a` conversion does use only as many digits in the exponent as needed, but it prints the value with hexadecimal.)

Comment: Detail: `"%a"` prints the (base 2) exponent in decimal.